# Use String#end_with?() but ignore case

Tags: ruby, regex, string

How to determine if string ends with another string regardless of its case?

```
filename.end_with?(*%w(.ext1 .e2 .extension))
```

This example only matches if the case matches too. How to match regardless of the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change filename to lowercase and compare with lowercase extensions.

```
filename.downcase.end_with?(*%w(.ext1 .e2 .extension))
```

---

```
'MAIN.RB'.downcase.end_with?(*%w(.ruby .rb)) # => true
```

Comment: Note that in this specific case this is (probably) fine but in general it’s **not** enough to `downcase` a string before comparison. For instance `"DASS".downcase.ends_with?("ß")` will *never* be true, but an invariant-case comparison between the two strings “DASS” and “daß” *should* return `true` (actually `casecmp` returns `-1` but that’s a bug).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Which operation yield true for `'ß'` and `'SS'` (or `'ss'`)?

Comment: In Ruby? I have no idea. But Unicode *mandates* that they compare true in case-invariant comparisons (the reason for this is that `'ß'.upcase` is defined as `SS` – it’s a German idiosyncrasy). Again Ruby doesn’t actually do this but once again this is simply because there’s a bug in Ruby’s string handling.